# Truncating ints without rounding?

Tags: python, floating-point, python-3.x, truncate

I made this program that takes change and figures out how many full dollars, and leftover change. The way it is setup, it takes the amount of change, 495 for example, and then converts it to dollars, 4.95. Now I want to cut off the .95 and leave the 4, how do I do this without it rounding up to 5? Thanks!

```
def main():
pennies = int(input("Enter pennies : "))
nickels = int(input("Enter nickels : "))
dimes = int(input("Enter dimes : "))
quarters = int(input("Enter quarters : "))

computeValue(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)

def computeValue(p,n,d,q):
print("You entered : ")
print("\tPennies  : " , p)
print("\tNickels  : " , n)
print("\tDimes    : " , d)
print("\tQuarters : " , q)

totalCents = p + n*5 + d*10 + q*25
totalDollars = totalCents / 100
totalDollarsTrunc = int(format(totalDollars, '.0f'))
totalPennies = totalCents - (totalDollarsTrunc * 100)

print("Amount of Change = ", totalDollarsTrunc, "dollars and ", totalPennies ,"cents.")

if totalCents < 100:
    print("Amount not = to $1")
elif totalCents == 100:
    print("You have exactly $1.")
elif totalCents >100:
    print("Amount not = to $1")
else:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: totalPennies = totalCents%100

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python, `int()` truncates when converting from `float`:

```
>>> int(4.95)
4
```

That said, you can rewrite

```
totalDollars = totalCents / 100
totalDollarsTrunc = int(format(totalDollars, '.0f'))
totalPennies = totalCents - (totalDollarsTrunc * 100)
```

using the `divmod` function:

```
totalDollars, totalPennies = divmod(totalCents, 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use `math.ceil` or `math.floor` to give you the rounding in the direction that you want.

Answer (score 2):

Function **int()** will do just that